# operator << overloading often fails if operator is const?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, overloading, ostream

If I want to overload the `<<` operator to use `cout` on a class, it should look like this:

```
template <typename coutT>
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &, const vector3D<coutT>&);
```

inside the class, and

```
template <typename coutT>
ostream& operator << (ostream & os,const vector3D<coutT>& v)
{
    os << "x: " << v.x<< "  y: " << v.y << "  z: " << v.z;
    return os; 
}
```

on the outside. Please take note of the `const` at the second operand.
This sample of code works just fine. Now to the problem.

If I were to write the overload function using the getters for the fields, instead of addressing them directly (since `operator<<` is a `friend`), my compiler would throw an error:

```
template <typename coutT>
ostream& operator << (ostream & os,const vector3D<coutT>& v)
{
   os << "x: " << v.getX() << "  y: " << v.getY()  << "  z: " << v.getZ();
   return os; 
}
```

The error:

> (VisualStudio2012) errorC2662: "this-pointer cannot be converted from "const vector3D" in "vector3D&""

An important note is that deleting the "const" at the second operand so that it's like

```
 ostream& operator << (ostream & os,vector3D<coutT>& v){...}
```

ended compiler errors, but since I don't want to change `v`, it should really be a const.

I should also mention that I think it may have to do with method calls in general, but I'm not sure.

---

edit:
So it is solved, declaring functions as const sticks to const-correctness.
The error message explains it in the way that it cannot cast the const type to a non-const one.

btw.: I'm actually impressed about the quick responses.

Comment: How are `getX` etc. declared?

Comment: Make sure that `getX()`, `getY()`, and `getZ()` are `const` member functions.

Comment: int getx(){return x;} so not const youre right

Comment: See [template friends problem](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends) - there are issues with your `friend` declaration. The way you've described in this question won't work.

Comment: The code works just fine, but i know what you mean M.M. It would be nice to use the class's template for the friend declarations since they only have to work for one type each, but thats not the topic here. Will definitely look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getter function should be declared `const` if you want to use it that way.

For example

```
int getValue() const {
    return x;
}
```

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
    int x;
public:

    Foo(int a) : x(a) {
    }

    int getValue() const {
        return x;
    }

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Foo & foo) {
        return out << foo.getValue();
    }

};

int main() {

    vector<Foo> foo_vec = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for (vector<Foo>::iterator it = foo_vec.begin(); it != foo_vec.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << ", ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you didn't mark the get functions `const`:

They need to look like this:

`double getX() const;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the accessor functions `const`:

```
struct V
{
    int getX() const { /* ... */ }
               ^^^^^
};
```

Only `const` member functions can be invoked on constant object values. In turn, const member functions cannot mutate the object. Thus const-correctness guarantees that a constant value cannot be mutated by invoking any of its member functions.